# Google SERP showing same page with different titles and URL pointing to the same website page

Tags: seo, google-index, search-results

I encountered a problem for my website page in Google SERP. I noticed that Google shows two different titles and URLs in the SERP. Both URLs point to the same page on my website.

[image]

This page was ranking on 1st page of Google and now after the problem, it is on the third page of Google SERP.

Answer (score 2):

I checked out your website and page, and everything looks right. Your XML sitemap, your JSON-LD structured data (testing tool did not detect the old URL), your robots.txt (but feel free to remove the `Allow: /` directive, as it's redundant), your canonical tag, your links in the nav... And the response to your old URL is a 301 redirect to your new URL... So it looks like you've done everything right.

The good news is, I did an incognito search for your page, and for the query "carpentry services in dubai" it came up in the middle of the second SERP, with the correct URL and title tag, and without the incorrect version.

How long ago did you change the URL and title tag, and had Google crawl it? While 301 redirects (and proper canonicalization and sitemap links and nav links) tell Google what the proper URL should be, sometimes it takes them time to notice and make the change. There's no set timeframe when these changes occur. But your page seems to be on its way.

Some other things you can do:

- Ask Google to re-crawl the site again in GSC, then note what got indexed.
- Use Screaming Frog to crawl the site, then note if the old URL is still active anywhere in your internal link structure.
- Implement a site-wide `<noarchive>` tag to ensure your site doesn't have any archived outdated snapshots in the search engines.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This will go a long way in helping me with this. However, I would let you know that I changed the URL at least 2 months ago and It was displaying correctly on the first page of Google SERP. This problem recently popped up.

Comment: @TaskMasters That does seem weird. There are other small factors that can contribute, besides the cacheing of the site. For example, maybe Google found an inbound link from somewhere with the old URL. But again, when I queried, I didn't see the old URL, and the correct one was on page 2, not 3, so maybe that's a sign on recovery. Try Open Site Explorer by Moz either way, to see what links to your page and how.

Answer (score 2):

When did this start?
Do you have any metas like og:title? If so, do they happen to be different than the actual title tag (whether or not they have any remnants of the old name/URL)?

I work on a pretty large site, and starting on Sept 15th or so at the latest  (could be a couple of days before but hard to know for sure), Google has been using the page's H1 tag for the title - instead of the actual, and better, title tag - a conditionally modified version of the H1 tag. After that weekend, impressions were up, rankings didn't go up or down more than the normal fluctuation of +/- 0.5-1.5, but CTR tanked. I'm curious if your title tag woes started at the same time - maybe it means something, maybe it doesn't.

I had a different site a few years ago that once had something more similar to your issue - Google was actually appending the company name to the end of the supplied title tag on a small, but still significant number of pages that used to have them, but like yours, it was a while ago and the new ones had been showing in the SERPs just fine until then. I don't remember how long it took to resolve, but it wasn't more than a few weeks. The suggestions given here are good ones, but I think it'll eventually resolve on its own, too.